# Cant download a file from Google Cloud Storage using Java API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to download atext file by usig Google Cloud Storage Java API as follow:

The file is located at "gs://bucket_name/dir/file.json

I am using below codes

```
bucket_name="name_of_bucket",
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucket_name, "dir/file.jason"));
//ReadChannel r = blob.reader();
return blob.toString();
```

However, whenever I using my code I get below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mahdi.handlers.GCSHandler.readJsonFile(GCSHandler.java:30)
        at com.mahdi.handlers.GCSHandler.main(GCSHandler.java:37)
```

I am not sure if I am giving right parameter for Bucket_Name and OBJECT_NAME in below line:

```
 Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, "dir/file.json"));
```

Comment: Which line is line 30?

Comment: And did you actually store the files as "j**a**son"?

Comment: return blob.toString();..and yes

Comment: "The file is located at "gs://bucket_name/dir/file.json" but you said that you actually stored it as "dir/file.jason". Which is it?

Comment: the file is 'file.json' located in 'dir' folder of 'bucket_name'

Comment: Now we've got 3 variants on the table: `json`, `jason` and `jaosn`.

Comment: all should be json sorry for typos